# Screenshot of layout in Android as PDF

Tags: android, android-layout, pdf, screenshot

I have created an activity in Android 5.1. Now I would like to take a picture as PDF of the layout. One possibility is to run the app (on a tablet) and then taking a screenshot using

```
adb shell screencap -p /sdcard/screen.png
adb pull /sdcard/screen.png
adb shell rm /sdcard/screen.png
```

Unfortunately, it is not possible to directly create a PDF (vector graphic). Is there a possibility to store the layout as a PDF?

Comment: There is nothing in the Android toolchain for this.

Comment: What is a possible usecase for this?

Comment: @ThomasRichter A png image gets unsharp when zoomed in while a vector graphic such as PDF remains sharp. I would like to use a screeshot of my app in a paper.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using linux, you can use imagemagick to convert the png to pdf

```
convert screen.png screen.pdf
```

Comment: I'm using windows but when converting png to pdf the problem remains that when zoomed in it gets unsharp

Comment: That is because Imagemagick is a raster processor and not a vector processor. So it puts the raster PNG into a vector PDF shell. So your PDF is really a raster image and when enlarged it will get blurry. You need some tool that does raster to vector processing, such as potrace.